# SoapUI groovy script error : No such property: log for class

Tags: groovy, soapui, modularity

I am trying to write a modular code in groovy inside soapui.
I have created a class Example having a method hello() that has a log.info statement.

I am creating an instance of this class to call the function hello.
On running the script i get the following error.

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: log for class: Example

Need help on this.

```
class Example{

  void hello(){
    log.info '    >>>>    Hello World';
  }

}

Example example = new Example();
example.hello();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example with complete script. Here log object is member variable and initialized using Constructor with map. Notice that here class is also present in the script itself. If it is a reusable, one has to copy past it in every script

```
class TestLogging {
  def log

  def sayHello(def name){
   log.info "Hello $name"
  }
}

def testLogging = new TestLogging(log:log)
testLogging.sayHello('Mr. ABC')
```

Usually when i write some groovy library classes, i use the following way to define class, create library and access the SOAPUI provided variables as well, and how to call from script. This will show the re-usability of the class- define once, reuse every where:

TestRunnerHelper.groovy -- compile & create a jar file and place it under SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext directory

```groovy
class TestRunnerHelper {
  def context
  def testRunner
  def log

  def printTestDetails() {
    log.info 'Name of the test case is :'+testRunner.testCase.name
    log.info 'Name of the test suite is : '+testRunner.testCase.testSuite.name
  }
}
```

Now write a script in any of your project->testsuite-> test case-> Groovy Script test step using the above class

```
def testHelper = new TestRunnerHelper(context:context, log:log, testRunner:testRunner)
testHelper.printTestDetails()
```

**Note** : if you have some package name in the groovy class, then it should be imported as well in the script.

What I wanted to convey through 2nd example is that you can write library classes in your favorite IDE(i wrote groovy, but one can use java as well) and leverage the variables context, log, testRunner variables provided by soapui by passing them to your classes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the direct and simple way to do it.

1. Inside the class declare log as a static variable.

   def static log;
2. Outside the class (Example) initialize it with log.

   Example.log = log;

Here is the complete code for it.

```
Example.log = log;
Example.hello();

class Example{

def static log;

    def static hello(){
        log.info ("Hello World...");
    }
}
```

In case of non static method. Create a class reference and call the function through it. E.g.

```
Example ex = new Example;
ex.hello();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can move out the log.info, still doing the same. thing.

```
class Example{

  String hello(){
    return  '    >>>>    Hello World';
  }

}

Example example = new Example();
log.info example.hello();
```

Comment: I need to figure out how to use log.info inside the function.

Comment: The requirement is i need to use log.info inside the function. Like inside hello() function in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
Here it is.
1. Need to put the class into context.
2. Need to pass log as object to the function.

Hope this helps others looking for similar solution.

```
class Example{

  void hello(Object log){
    log.info '    >>>>    Hello World';
  }

}

context = new Example();
context.hello(log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for adding log inside class function and to call this function from other (outside) script.

Create a Groovy Step in SoapUI (TestLogging) and add the following code:

```
class TestLogging
{
   def log;
   def context;
   def testRunner;

    def sayHello()
      {
          log.info ("Hello ");
    }

}

context.setProperty("testClass", new TestLogging(log:log,context:context,testRunner:testRunner));
```

Add another script and add the following code to add the function of TestLogging class:

```
tSuite = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["TestSuiteName"]

module = tSuite.testCases["TestCaseName"].testSteps["TestLogging"]

// initialise the tSuite; which places an instance of TestLogging in the context
module.run(testRunner, context)

// get the instance of TestLogging Class from the context.
def testClass= context.testClass

//call function
testClass.sayHello();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `log` with class name and you should declare `log` as `static` inside the class as shown below:

```
Example.log = log    
class Example {    
  def static log    
  public void hello()            
  {        
    log.info '    >>>>    Hello World';        
  }  
}        

Example example = new Example();      
example.hello();
```